# Subversion - Retrieval of mergeinfo unsupported

Tags: svn

I've recently updated my Subversion package on Debian Etch to 1.5.1 via a back-port. I've gone through what I believe are all the appropriate steps but cannot for the life of me get past the following error message when I try to merge:

> Retrieval of mergeinfo unsupported by
>   '.'

The '.' isn't important as I get the same message whether I'm SSH'd on to the server or using TortoiseSVN through Windows.

I'll take you through what I did to upgrade and test step by step:

**Update of Subversion**

Added the following line to /etc/apt/sources.list:

> deb http://www.backports.org/debian
>   etch-backports main contrib non-free

and then ran

> apt-get -s -t etch-backports install
>   subversion

**Checked the version of the subversion installation**

Done this by running

> svnadmin --version

and got the following output:

> svnadmin, version 1.5.1 (r32289)
>   compiled Dec 11 2008, 18:10:14

Checked the client too using

> svn --version

and got the following

> svn, version 1.5.1 (r32289)
>   compiled Dec 11 2008, 18:10:14

Ok, so all looking good so far.

Now I just need to upgrade the repository. After plenty of research, the most foolproof way to do this seemed to be to dump the repository and then load it again. So here's what I did:

> svnadmin dump /var/svn/repo > repo.dump
>
> rm -aR /var/svn/repo/*
>
> svnadmin create /var/svn/repo
>
> svnadmin load < repo.dump

All that seemed to work fine. I then checked to see if the repository had been upgraded by looking at the contents of **/var/svn/repo/db/format** which gave:

> 3
>
> layout sharded 1000

Again this indicated a Subversion 1.5 repository so all looking good.

Now I try and do a merge using the Subversion client in Debian:

> svn mergeinfo https://mysvn/repo .

and I get the following error:

> svn: Retrieval of mergeinfo unsupported by '.'

I get the same error message whether I'm using the Debian shell on the same server or if I'm connecting via TortoiseSVN and a Windows box.

If I browse to the repository using my web browser, the version number at the bottom reads:

> Powered by Subversion version 1.4.2 (r22196).

In case it helps, the created date on **mod_dav_svn.so** is **2009-08-06 18:29**

I just cannot figure out why I'm getting this message so any help pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. All the forum and mailing list posts that I found relating to this error were solved by doing an svnadmin upgrade, though I have actually tried that and still no joy.

Thanks in advance,

James.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your server version is too old (1.4.2).  Your client, svnadmin, and repository are all at least 1.5, which is good, but I think your server itself needs to be at least 1.5 as well to support a "merge --reintegrate"

Answer (score 3):

It was the mod_dav_svn module that was out of date. I fixed this by running the following:

> apt-get -t etch-backports install libapache2-svn

Thanks to the Subversion users mailing list for pin-pointing this.

Thanks,

James.